# Linux Mint Cinnamon: logging out of one user terminates X of other user

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have several user sessions on a laptop with `X` sessions started (`Cinnamon` on `Linux Mint 19`). Every time when I log out via Cinnamon GUI another user have X session terminated (I find CLI when I switch via Ctl+alt+F). Why is that? Any particular innnerworkings of Cinnamon or/and X user sessions behave that way for all desktop environments? I could not find about that issue via web search (I guess not many try to use PC that way...).

ADDED: I long time ago noticed I cannot start several Cinnamon sessions on a laptop for same user, I took it as a limitation; have not tried the same with other desktops. That is why I started to use several user accounts in the first place.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Are you displaying the X sessions on the same or different client computers?

Comment: @sudodus, same laptop, do ctl-alt-f then login then `startx` which starts Cinnamon

Comment: If not a bug it might be a 'missing feature' - maybe Cinnamon was never made to work like that. You can try (in a live session booted from a USB drive) with another desktop environment (gnome, KDE, XFCE ...) or maybe even better to try with a simple window manager (not a full desktop environment), for example Fluxbox or Openbox.

Comment: What happens if you let Linux Mint start the desktop environment automatically and you switch user without logging out (in the graphical user interface, not via `startx`), so that you have two users logged in at the same instance of Cinnamon, and then go back and logout from the first user? I have done this in gnome and LXDE and it works (in Ubuntu and Lubuntu).

Comment: @sudodus, now I've tried the same on other laptop and it's working fine with mostly "empty" new sessions. Maybe some corruption with current install or maybe it happens on high memory load/usage...

Comment: That is a good result :-) I think you are getting closer to a solution.

Comment: @sudodus, should I run some log extraction after next "event"? can you advice what to look for?

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at logging events. I think you can look for tips via the internet, ask a new question about that or wait and hope that someone else will see your question and help you.